# How to modify the status bar and title background color in SSMS(18) when using extension pack？

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ssms, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I created a extension pack project,when document opend,I want to modify document color when I use different sql connection.

I can get the DTE and WindowActivated event only.

```cs
dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
dte.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated += OnWindowCreated;
```

I want get this result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKF4Q.png)

Comment: You can check/search here: [.NET API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) to see if there are some APIs that you need. For example, check [EnvironmentColors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=visualstudiosdk-2019&term=EnvironmentColors).

Answer (score 0):

In our application we set color something like this

```
IVsWindowFrame frame;
frame.GetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_DocView, out object docView);
var strip = GetPrivateMember<System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip>(docView, "statusBar");
strip.BackColor = _your_color_;
```

`IVsWindowFrame` for example you can get in such way - you can create the implementation for `IVsRunningDocTableEvents3` and store frame for your document in this method

`public int OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(uint docCookie, int fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)`